# Fancybox - how to set title for iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I'm trying to set the title for the FancyBox to be the iFrame page `<title>` (or anything specific to that particular iframe - there are four different ones on the page).

Whatever I do I either get the parent page title or nothing - often no fancybox either.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit - some snippets:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.iframe").fancybox({
        'width':1000,
        'height':760,
        'titlePosition': 'inside',
        'titleShow':true
    });
});
```

and...

```
<a class="iframe linkText" href="productinfo.cfm" title="test title">What do these products do?</a>
```

Comment: I've added a couple of snippets. The title attribute gives a hover tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just

```
$("a.linkText").fancybox({
    'width':1000,
    'height':760,
    'titlePosition': 'inside',
    'titleShow':true
});
```

And then

```
<a href="..." class="iframe" title="This is the title">Open iFrame</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the title attribute on the link?

```
<a href="..." class="iframe" title="This is the title">Open iFrame</a>
```

Comment: Yep, tried that. The only way I can get it to show anything is by adding 'title':document.title to the init. Then it shows the parent page title.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if using the class `iframe` as your selector is causing some sort of conflict. Fancybox uses this class to denote the content of the fancybox so maybe this is the issue.

Try changing your jQuery code to:

```
$("a.linkText").fancybox({
    'width':1000,
    'height':760,
    'titlePosition': 'inside',
    'titleShow':true
});
```

Comment: Nope. Still just the same. I'll have to leave this until Monday now, but thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and solved it by adding `'title': this.title` which showed the title /caption below the video finally. Example code for embedding a youtube video with iframe:

```
$('.popupvideo').click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'title': this.title,
        'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp('watch\\?v=', 'i'), 'embed/') + '?showinfo=0&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=0&amp;vq=large',
        'overlayShow' : true,
        'centerOnScroll' : true,
        'speedIn' : 100,
        'speedOut' : 50,
        'width' : 640,
        'height' : 480,
        'scrolling' : 'no'
    });
    return false;
});
```